# Create a button with animated gradient in borders

Tags: css, animation, button, gradient

I am currently building a website and I would like to create a button with the following elements:

- Black background
- White text
- Animated gradient on the borders
- Blurred borders

The idea is to get a button that looks like this one:

[image: excepted button] I'm sorry I couldn't get any better quality nor example

I managed to get the following result:

[image: actual button] (It's actually animated)

Here is the code I am currently using:

```css
@keyframes gradient {
    to {
      background-position: 200% center;
    }
}

#degradebtn {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#degradebtn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px; 
  left: -6px; 
  right: -6px; 
  bottom: -6px; 
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, lime, cyan, blue, magenta, red);
  background-size: 800% auto;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: gradient 8s infinite linear;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I don't really know what can I do now, I didn't see anyone else asking for this before.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add some HTML to your demo so we can see the CSS being applied to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `border-radius` and `filter:blur()` are the missing properties needed to get the desired result

```css
body {
  margin: 30px;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  to {
    background-position: 200% center;
  }
}

#degradebtn {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#degradebtn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, lime, cyan, blue, magenta, red);
  background-size: 800% auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: gradient 8s infinite linear;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a id="degradebtn">See in action</a>
</body>
```